# using WebAPI OAuth Token in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a standalone WebAPI Application that returns a token when authenticating against it.  When I make calls back to the API and send the token in the header the API is able to retrieve the claims and roles of that token.

However when I consume that API and get the token in a separate MVC Application I only have access to some limited properties like the access_token, token_type, expires_in, etc.

Is it good practice to return custom claims and user roles in that response result?  Or should I make an additional call to the API to return the user claims and user roles and update the existing token?